# Huge dictionary Python not working

Tags: python, dictionary, process, large-data

I have a really big dictionary in Python . . . it isn't compiling in CodeRunner or in Xcode

I have a list that's not that big that i'm trying to translate but it isn't working correctly because the dictionary is so big . . 23124 keys in the dictionary .  **Is there a way to process large dictionaries by creating a database or something ?**

When I copy and paste my dictionary into CodeRunner or in Xcode, the colors do not change for the different types of elements like strings or integers.

When I run this, I get a larger output than my input

```
#D_ens_g = {"big" dictionary w/ >20k keys and values}

def Simple_Reader(input,output='test.txt'):
    temp = []

    query=open(input,'r').read().split('\r')
    for q in query:
        print D_ens_g[q]

test_2 = '~/Desktop/list.txt'
Simple_Reader(test_2)
```

every element in the list that I import in test_2 has a particular ID that is in the keys of the dictionary

Comment: "big" isn't a number.

Comment: use a real database? (or even something like sqlite3, or couchdb)

Comment: First, do you actually _need_ that large dictionary?

Comment: i don't know how else I would do it.  how can i generate a database? big as in 20k+ . i've compiled the dictionary using a bunch of different data files

Comment: is there a limit to how large dictionaries can be ? maybe there's a way to generate a database type structure in python that i don't know about

Comment: the limit is imposed by your system memory ... you could convert it to a sqlite database pretty simply Im sure

Comment: @JBernardo Haven't you heard of big data. Its pretty big right now. How big? Really big.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't compiling"? And 20k+ what? What's in the dict? Do you get an error message? Can you show us the error message? (The *whole* error message?)

Comment: @user2357112 I didn't think those details were necessary to put in ? There are 23124 keys in my dictionary and they are all IDs of 18 characters long. Do I get an error message ? No . When I say it isn't compiling I mean when I copy and paste the dictionary into CodeRunner or Xcode, the colors do not change and everything remains white.  When I run it, I get different results.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr i like the sarcasm. doesn't help with my question tho.  i thought this was a relevant problem and i'd rather not be mocked for it

Comment: Assuming a 19-byte key, and just for sake of argument, assume the value is the same size, 25K keys and values only requires about 1MB of memory (maybe 2MB, once you account for link structures, hash buckets, etc.). Unless you're running on a really old system, I suspect the size of your dictionary is not the issue here...

Comment: @draconisthe0ry: You sure it's not just overwhelming the syntax highlighting? The actual code could be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

do you actually need a large dictionary? Presumably you are pulling data from another file. What do you need to actually do with the dictionary? A real database might be smarter as Joran says

Comment: this should be a comment (I realize you dont have enough rep for a comment so I wont downvote... but its gonna end up getting downvoted as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

so what I did is i made a text file with the "big" dictionary and then i imported ast and used literal_eval to just read it without having to compile it in my application

```
import ast
D_ens_gene = ast.literal_eval(open('/users/opus_magnum/desktop/D_ens_gene.txt','r').read())
```